# How to generate script to retrieve schema and only top 100 records from each table from SQL Server 2005

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

How to generate script to retrieve schema and only top 100 records from each table from SQL Server 2005. I need to generate scripts for 15-16 databases and each database has more than 50-60 tables. Is it possible to generate script to retrieve schema only some data in SQL Server 2005? If yes, how can I do this? Any help appreciated.

Comment: It should be quite straightforward, just look into the DMVs, at least sys.databases, sys.tables and sys.columns

Comment: The top 100 rows is pretty simple but what do you mean by "retrieve schema"? Are you wanting to create the script to create all the tables?

Comment: @JamesZ yes I know sys.tables and all.i am developer not db admin,i want to generate script schema with data.and here data mean not full data i just want first 100-200 record as a sample.the data is quite huge.each db more than 2-3 GB.

Comment: @SeanLange Yes, I want to generate script to retrieve schema and only Top 100 records from each table.and each database have more than 50 tables,some of them have 180 tables.so I even  dont want to update generated script before it executing.any help would be appreciated.thanks

Comment: Just use a cursor to loop sys.databases and sys.tables, create schema based on sys.columns and run "select top 100 * from " + tablename?

Comment: Scripting schema automatically can get incredibly complicated. Consider how challenging it is when you have constraints using function or that sort of thing. Also, to properly script schema you need to include foreign keys. This is also challenging because you now have to script objects in the right order. This kind of thing is just what you want to do in an automated script. You will spend more time figuring our how to write the script (and still likely incorrect) than just doing it manually.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @query varchar(max)
set @query = ''
select @query = @query + 'select top 100 * from [' + t.name + '];' from sys.tables t order by t.name
exec (@query)
```

Comment: :Thank you for your response!.I want to generate script for schema with selected data.do you have any idea how to do it?